# Show modal on load page by default and dont close Modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have the next script in JS and I want to open Modal on load page with **.modal('show')** but also I want this Modal dont close on click. I've seen in Internet **.modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })** but both things combined do not work, the only thing I get is to show the modal but it closes when I click on it.

My button Modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary show-modal"  data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ambitModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>
```

And my JS:

```
$('#ambitModal').modal('show', { backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false }); // show modal
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this way

```
$('#ambitModal').modal({
  show: true,
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false
})

Or 

$('#ambitModal').modal({
  show: true, { backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false }
})
```